# Laravel 5.2 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, laravel-5

My project was running well. After adding 3 new columns to a table, I run a artisan command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

But action did not complete. After that, when I run any migration command, it is throwing an error massage .

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'telemedicine.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `status` = 0 and `mailconfirm` = 1)

Note:

I deleted all tables and run `php artisan migration` But the problem remains. I  I can't understand why.

```
(SQL: select * from `users` where `status` = 0 and `mailconfirm` = 1)
```

This query is running in migration period.

Comment: whats in your model? have you specified $table and $fillable properties?

Comment: Yes,I have written " protected $fillable = ['*'];" in my model;

Comment: did you try to run this query(not in laravel), in terminal or in some mysql's IDE? is it working?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand.

Comment: I mean try to run this query select * `from `users` where `status` = 0 and `mailc
 onfirm` = 1` in pure php(without laravel) or in phpmyadmin, or some text editor. make sure your sql statement is correct and no errors there

Comment: I think, I am unable to express my problem. Now in my Database there is no table. I have deleted  all tables from phpMyadmin. But stile now when I am running migration command, the same massage is throwing.

Comment: check the name of tables in both(in mysql and in laravel). is your table empty? you said you dropped it, is there any data in table?

Comment: why dont you want to run this query in phpmyadmin?)) or you already run it?

Comment: oh! Just I want to create table using artisan command. By the by  I have commented My Query  from my model, Now  new error massage is throwing "
 [BadMethodCallException]
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAllinactiveU
 sers()" When running migrationcommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the name of the tables to your Model Class.
public $table = "users";

Answer (score 6):

Thank you Everybody. I have already solved my problem. I used a function **getAllinactiveUsers**  in ***boot*** function of **AppServiceprovider class**. The  dafination of **getAllinactiveUsers**  function was written in the *Model Class*. So when I tried to run *php artisan* command to create table in the *phpMyadmin*, The **getAllinactiveUsers** was invoked before creating the table. For this reason such Error was throwing.

```
Solution:
```

Just commented The **getAllinactiveUsers** function from  **AppServiceprovider class**, and run php artisan command. Everything is ok.

Comment: check your answer as answered

Answer (score 0):

Please check your validation properly  eg 'tag' => 'required|unique:tag|max:255' error
                                          'tag' => 'required|unique:tags|max:255' correct